# C++ object creation and destruction

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I was messing around with a class and the constructor and destructor but now i'm not sure what is going on and hopefully someone here can explain why this is happening.

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
Animal dog1 = Animal("Thor");
Animal *pDog2 = &Animal("Loki");
Animal *pDog3 = new Animal("New");
```

The class just has a constructor that prints that the constructor and/or destructor is being invoked with the name of the Animal. What i see in the output, however, is that pDog2 is being created but right after that it is being destroyed. I have no idea why since it is not going out of scope yet, right?

The output given is:

> ```
> Constructor of Thor called. 
> Constructor of Loki called. 
> Destructor of Loki called. 
> Constructor of New called.
> ```

Hopefully someone can help me explain this.

Comment: It most certainly goes out of scope. A temporary object that gets created in an expression gets destroyed when the expression finishes evaluating (there are some exceptions to this rule, but they do not apply here). You are creating a temporary object and taking its pointer. That's wonderful, but that temporary object gets destroyed as soon as the expression finishes evaluating. This is how C++ works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Animal *pDog2 = &Animal("Loki");
```

What happens here is:

1. A temporary object of type `Animal` is created: `Animal("Loki")`. The output *"Constructor of Loki called."* is shown.
2. The address of this temporary is assigned to `pDog2`.
3. The temporary is destroyed at the end of the full expression: `Animal *pDog2 = &Animal("Loki");` and the output *"Destructor of Loki called."* is shown.

After that `pDog2` becomes a dangling pointer as the temporary it pointed to doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: All of this is a Microsoft extension though. The operand of `&` (unless overloaded) must be an lvalue or a qualified-id.

Comment: @Edgar Rokjan But at the end of program all the objects gets created i are destroyed in c++ by invokation of destructor.

Comment: @StoryTeller yes, the preferable way is to use `/permissive-` :)

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala Agree, but I don't see the output from destructor for *New* so I mentioned this.

Comment: @EdgarRokjān because there is stack pointer to heap memory .So we have to invoke manually to delete the memory

Comment: Hello Edgar, thank you for your response. Then i don't understand the difference between the first 2 lines. Arent they both supposed be temporary objects in the scope of main in this case? I didn't post the delete pDog3; line but it is included in the main method.

Comment: @SSJVegetto In the first line you construct a new object on stack from a temporary. Then this object exists until `dog1` goes out of scope. In the second line you create a pointer to temporary and the temporary is then destroyed in the end of the full expression.

Comment: @EdgarRokjān Does this mean that the first line will create a new object and assign it to a variable in the scope of main where the second line creates a temporary object and the reference is passed to pDog2 which then thus means the object gets destroyed right after the expression? Thank you very much for your explanation.

Comment: @SSJVegetto Animal dog1=Animal("Thor"); is same as Animal dog1("Thor");

Comment: @SSJVegetton When you use new keyword then an object is created in heap memory and that address is given to a pointer or reference created in stack.As simple as such.Therefore no new object is created.Moreover,dog1 is not a pointer .

Comment: @GaneshChowdharySadanala : That sounds kind of weird to me, the new keyword does create a new object only in the heap and the pointer is returned right? So a new object IS created? I know you have alternative ways of creating a new object and i know that dog1 is not a pointer. I was having trouble with the scope of the objects. But thanks for your reply.

Comment: @SSJVegetto dog1 has a main() scope and pDog2 has that expression scope(note that the heap object only deallocated at that expression not the pointer)